# Unos en un número

Tags: c++, c

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe hacer este ejercicio? Es que no entiendo muy bien la recursividad en C, C++ y necesito saber como se hace este ejercicio.

Yo lo he hecho de esta forma:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int recursiva (int num) {
      int contador = 0;
      int resto = 0;
      if (num/10 == 0) {
        resto = num;
      } else {
        contador = recursiva(num/10);
        resto = num % 10;
      }
        if (resto == 1) {
            contador++;
        }

      }

     int main () {
         int numero, digitos;
         cout << "Introduce el número "; cin >> numero; cout << endl;
         cout << recursiva(numero);


        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Para entender la recursividad, primero hay que entender la recursividad. No me hagas caso, es un chiste viejo de informáticos.

Comment: Ya lo he editado, con las cosas que tenia hechas, es que no sabia como poner codigo, porque antes lo puse de casualidad

Comment: Recursividad es la misma en cualquier lenguaje (hasta donde se). Un ciclo que ejecuta instrucciones hasta que haya un punto de ruptura. Sin este punto se ejecutaria un bucle infinito. Te pregunto...¿En que momento tu funcion recursiva deja de llamarse a si misma? o lo que es lo mismo ¿Cuando termina? Una respuesta pudiera ser cuando `contador` tenga determinado valor o haya alguna variable estatica obersvadora que alcanzado cierto valor detenga la recursividad

Comment: Ya has puesto tu código... ¿falla en algo? ¿funciona pero no lo entiendes? ¿?

Answer (score 1):

[Recursión](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursi%C3%B3n) es cuando una función se llama a si misma.

Puedes hacer una función recursiva para contar la cantidad de 1 de un número:

- Llamando a la misma función dentro del número con un dígito menos.
- Devolviendo si en esa recursión ha detectado un uno.

Es tan sencillo como esto:

```
int recursiva(int n)
{
    return n ? (n % 10 == 1) + recursiva(n / 10) : 0;
}
```

En C++ un valor booleano se puede convertir implícitamente a entero (`int`) siendo el valor `false` transformado en `0` y el valor `true` en `1`, así pues la expresión `(n % 10 == 1)` será `0` para valores diferentes a `1` si a eso le sumamos los valores devueltos por el valor de la siguiente llamada a `recursiva` con un dígito menos, obtendremos la cantidad de unos de un número.

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/NCoJAFIXXzlMcjECpSNM2/rXuMWRmkAG9I@NMm@jF2vZglhYiLQ/3Ox/n8r4/NJyP40YRb52QKJQerJF1VzGmyMJI7sygbnUwJQrZnXlGWmcIhAsCwhZxhLJEHGK3wgnHzyFEhihnj6@sqxUFs2KWuU4avYdQjbJ6yJk3WJFlXDuLooB/JWu0cFxCtqDXc6LhL5giVNVP8t@dgyTRTmG1aYbDnC0/TNvGMT4l6TlNTjF7Aw)</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

borra  *int digitos*, no lo usas para nada.
Te doy comentarios sobre el código, para que lo entiendas.

Recursividad, es invocar al mismo bloque de código, en si mismo, pero sin olvidar la condición  de parada, para que no se ejecute indefinidamente hasta agotar los recursos de memoria y/o procesamiento, algo que veo por tu código te estuvo pasando si el número terminaba en cero.

Prueba con esta:

```
int recursiva (int num) 
{
int contador = 0;
if(abs(num) > 9) 
    {//entonces num tiene aún 2 o más dígitos 
    if((abs(num) % 10) == 1) contador++; //verificar si el digito a la derecha es un 1, agregar al contador
    //Iterar recursivamente con el resto, y agregar sus resultados al contador.
    contador += recursiva(num / 10);
    }
if(abs(num) == 1) contador++;
return contador;
}
```

Comment: Puestos en tu línea de **borrar**: La conversión a `int` es totalmente innecesaria, deberías reducir el ámbito de `resto` (e incluso podrías eliminar esa variable), el `else` es perfectamente evitable y el comentario en la línea en la que asignas `resto` no tiene demasiado sentido

Comment: De acuerdo totalmente con el casting a int, la división es entre enteros así que el resultado será entero, innecesaria. También el else es evitable. Bueno el comentario. Gracias!   Quise decir que el número lo descompones así RESTO*10 +  DIGITO_DERECHA

Answer (score 0):

Primero que todo, tu funcion *recursiva* no retorna ningun valor. Corrigiendo este  error todo me funciona perfectamente:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int recursiva(int num)
{
    int contador = 0;
    int resto = 0;
    if (num/10 == 0)
    {
        resto = num;
    }
    else
    {
        contador = recursiva(num/10);
        resto = num % 10;
    }

    if (resto == 1)
    {
        contador++;
    }
    return contador;
}

int main ()
{
    int numero, digitos;
    cout << "Introduce el número "; cin >> numero; cout << endl;
    cout << recursiva(numero);
    return 0;
}
```